# Why is it inefficient to duplicate jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, duplicates

Why is it inefficient to duplicate jQuery selectors?

E.g.:

```
$('.tags-list .active').removeClass('btn-primary');
// then somewhere else on the page
$('.tags-list .active').text('active'); // warning duplicate
```

To fix this is to add an extra line of code.

```
const activeTag = $('.tags-list .active');
activeTAg.removeClass('btn-primary');
// then somewhere else on the page
$('.tags-list .active').text('active');
```

Comment: The second one is not efficient yet. In last line you should use `activeTag` again.

Comment: And you could load jquery  and fetch element once and chain jquery  methods... `$('.tags-list .active').removeClass('btn-primary').text('active';`

Comment: It's inefficient because when you recall the selector it has to search the DOM for the element or elements and then creates a new object holding all the data related to the results. Do this a ton of times with large collections of matched elements and now you're using much more resources than needed. Creating a var the first time and reusing it later avoids all that.

Comment: @ikiK I think you missed the comment `// then somewhere else on the page`... kind of precludes chaining.

Comment: Note that it is not necessarily *bad* to have the inefficiency. For instance, if you know you're going to be toggling the `active` class, then it may make sense to rerun the query, since the list of matched elements has changed. What you don't want is what I've seen a lot of, which is a stack of 10 queries of exactly the same selector, with each of the 10 changing a single CSS style. Not *that's* inefficient.

Comment: @Wesley Makes total sense. If I'm using a selector many times across a large file I'll definitely create a `const foobar = $('foobar')` at the top of the file, but if it's just two instances, I probably won't create a var. It's more that IDE warnings are annoying, but at the same time, I don't want to turn off that inspection.